# File.Copy target file is a directory, not a file.

Tags: c#

I am probably not doing this correctly, and browsing the MSDN library hasn't helped me much. I am trying to copy my database from my project folder to another location. I initially tried the desktop, and it stated the directory was not available. This is what I currently have.

```
private string currentDb = @"J:\Project\Project\HotelDB.accdb",
               backUpPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
               newFileName = @"\";
```

I call it with this method. The error I currently get is that the Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments class indicates that 'My Documents' is a folder, not a file. This tells me that I'm doing this all wrong. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
public void backupDatabase()
{
    File.Copy(currentDb, backUpPath, true);
}
```

Comment: Then you should target the same path, but with the file name appended to it. This is because you can also rename the file while you copy it

Comment: You are copying J:\Project\Project\HotelDB.accdb to C:\foo for example, you need to copy to C:\foo\HotelDB.accdb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add the filename to the target path.
This is clearly specified in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx

> The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an
>   existing file.

For example:

```
"J:\Project\Project\HotelDB.accdb"
```

Should go to:

```
"c:\HotelDB.accdb"
```

(And not `"C:\"`)

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that such an answer (harmfully) promotes the "give a man a fish" mindset instead of "teach a man to fish"? The documentation is so easy to find: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx

Comment: I understand your concern, Roliu. I had already read the documentation you linked. I will read it over again and try to find what I missed.

Comment: @roliu Yes, ofcourse. I've added the link and quote in my post.

Answer (score 3):

As MSDN States

> destFileName
>   Type: System.String
>   The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory.

So add the name of the file to the destination path.

[File.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/9706cfs5.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 private string currentDb = @"J:\Project\Project\HotelDB.accdb",
 backUpPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"\HotelDB.accdb"
```