# Copy mapped file to other folder named Test_Performance_WithFilledExcelFile C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

```
   public void Test_Performance_WithFilledExcelFile()
    {
        // given
        var lorenzBahlsenCicToExcelJobWorker = new LorenzBahlsenCicToExcelJobWorker();
        var environment = new TestEnvironment(lorenzBahlsenCicToExcelJobWorker, nameof(Test_Performance_WithFilledExcelFile));

        string binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location);
        var testFile = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "TestFiles", CICSynchronisedTestFile);

        var excelFileCurrent = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "TestFiles", "next_delivery.xlsx");
        var excelFolderTarget = environment.EnvironmentDataStoragePath;


        File.Copy(excelFileCurrent, excelFolderTarget);
     }
```

I have a question regarding the copy file,  why when I want to copy the file to the destination I have an exception:

> "Could not load the specified file"

However, when I debug the code I have an exception that :

> The target file
>   'C:\Project\lorenz-bahlsen\LorenzBahlsen.CICtoExcel.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Environments\Test_Performance_WithFilledExcelFile\data-storage'
>   is a directory, not a file.'

Can you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File.Copy target file is a directory, not a file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332772/file-copy-target-file-is-a-directory-not-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-1.1#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_), File.Copy expects that you will provide destination file name, not a folder name.
So, in your example it would be:

```
 public void Test_Performance_WithFilledExcelFile()
    {
        // given
        var lorenzBahlsenCicToExcelJobWorker = new LorenzBahlsenCicToExcelJobWorker();
        var environment = new TestEnvironment(lorenzBahlsenCicToExcelJobWorker, nameof(Test_Performance_WithFilledExcelFile));

        string binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location);
        var testFile = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "TestFiles", CICSynchronisedTestFile);

        var excelFileCurrent = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "TestFiles", "next_delivery.xlsx");
        var excelFolderTarget = environment.EnvironmentDataStoragePath;
        var destinationFile = Path.Combine(excelFolderTarget, "next_delivery.xlsx");

        File.Copy(excelFileCurrent, destinationFile);
     }
```